# How Do I Use Multiple Values in a Tuple for a Function Argument That Takes One Argument

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a fuction that does math that takes the inputs of 2 sets of tuples and use the index of the tuples to do the math, versus having 4 variables.

```
class numbers():
    def points(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        return self.x, self.y
    
    def maths(self, *args):
        foobar1 = self.x, self.y
        foobar2 = args[0], args[1]
        return foobar1[0] - foobar2[0] + foobar1[1] - foobar2[1]
        
        

num1 = numbers()
num2 = numbers()
num1.points(4, 10)
num2.points(5, 11)

num2.maths(num1.points)
```

What I would like is the argument in `def maths()` to take both points from `num1.points`(4, 10) so that I can use the two points in a similar manner to `num2.x` and `num2.y`

Comment: `num1.points` is your `points` method, not a tuple. Also why don't you simply pass the other object in? `num2.maths(num1)` and `def maths(self, other)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making a constructor **init** to initialize your class variables x and y. You can remove the points function and instead of passing a tuple for the maths function, if you plan to pass the x and y variables of another numbers object, you can pass another number object instead.

```
class numbers():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def maths(self, otherNumberObj):
        foobar1 = self.x, self.y
        foobar2 = otherNumberObj.x, otherNumberObj.y
    
        return foobar1[0] - foobar2[0] + foobar1[1] - foobar2[1]

num1 = numbers(4, 10)
num2 = numbers(2, 5)

print(num2.maths(num1))
```

If you really want to keep the function maths as passing a tuple into it, you could do something like this:

```
class numbers():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def maths(self, someTuple):
        foobar1 = self.x, self.y
        foobar2 = someTuple[0], someTuple[1]
    
        return foobar1[0] - foobar2[0] + foobar1[1] - foobar2[1]

num1 = numbers(4, 10)
num2 = numbers(2, 5)

print(num2.maths((num1.x, num1.y)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way, but this got it working (very similar to Abdul Barkat and BWallDev):

```
class numbers():
    def points(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        return self.x, self.y
    
    def maths(self, other):
        foobar1 = self.x, self.y
        foobar2 = other.x, other.y
        return foobar1[0] - foobar2[0] + foobar1[1] - foobar2[1]
        
        

num1 = numbers()
num2 = numbers()
num1.points(5, 11)
num2.points(10, 22)

print(num2.maths(num1))
>>> 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to have a class to support the points then the *maths()* function of the *numbers* class can take references to a *points* class. Something like this:

```
class numbers:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def maths(self, p1, p2):
        return p1._x - p1._y + p2._x - p2._y

class points:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

p1 = points(4, 10)
p2 = points(5, 11)

print(numbers().maths(p1, p2))
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to update the `maths` method to let `foobar2` accept a tuple.

```py
def maths(self, *args):
    foobar1 = self.x, self.y
    # foobar2 = args[0], args[1]
    foobar2 = args[0]
    return foobar1[0] - foobar2[0] + foobar1[1] - foobar2[1]
```

Then you can pass a tuple to `maths`.

```py
num2.maths((num1.x, num1.y))
```

Another way to do this is to add another function to create the tuple for you.

```py
def get_point(self):
    return (self.x, self.y)
```

Then do

```py
num2.maths(num1.get_point())
```

That being said, having `*args` and the assignment of the variables to `foobar1/2` is unnecessary and can be simplified to the following:

```py
def maths(self, t2):
    return self.x - t2.x + self.y - t2.y
```

Further more it would also be better to initialize the points when you create the `numbers` object, so full refactored it would look like:

```py
class Numbers():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def maths(self, t2):
        return self.x - t2.x + self.y - t2.y
    
    def get_point(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)
        
num1 = Numbers(4, 10)
num2 = Numbers(5, 11)

num2.maths((num1.x, num1.y))
num2.maths(num1.get_point())
```